# DocuSign - how to get signed document?

Tags: docusignapi

Im trying to get signed document with rest API in postman. When using demo account.

I found out that the url need to be the base URL+uri from the API call.
I tried this:
[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents/certificate](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/envelopes/$%7BenvelopeId%7D/documents/certificate)
and i got 404 message.

How can i get the url for the signed document?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `/accounts/{account_id}/` portion of the URL, see what URL should look like:

```
${base_path}/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/documents/{doc_choice
```

- **archive**: Retrieves a ZIP archive that contains all of the PDF
  documents and the Certificate of Completion.
- **certificate**: Retrieves
  the Certificate of Completion as a PDF file.
- **portfolio**: Retrieves the
  envelope documents as a PDF portfolioPDF portfolio, opens in new
  window.

For detailed code and more information - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/